# Creating millions of tasks to concurrently get data from api for each item

Tags: c#, optimization, concurrency, async-await, task

I have a database table with a couple of millions records.
For each record I need to get some additional data via API.

So I am trying to utilize concurrency in C# with Task and async-await pattern.
For each record I am creating a `Task` and within it I am calling an api using `HttpClient`.

Unfortunately this yields Out of memory exception.

```
IEnumerable<Task<Item>> tasks =
            items.Select(
                async i => await GetItemDataFromApi(i));

            var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Is this a way to do it? Should I create a task for getting each record's data?

Comment: You really need to read all those rows concurrently? Can your db handle that load? Can't you retrieve batches and modify the api to return additional data for a set of records? I am really curious about your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for a million of Task objects in Task.WhenAll at least needs an array with these millions of objects. Beside the memory consumption it will increase the burden on your system to manage all these objects. Some ideas for general improvement:

- Create batches- put several rows (e.g. thousand) in one management class that are processed concurrently
- Do not instantiate a HttpClient for each Task. The same HttpClient object can be used concurrently and helps to limit resource usage of sockets.
- Throttle the usage of the Web API - I cannot imagine that anyone is happy if their server is hit by millions of requests in a short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

the Web server has a limit, what I think you need to do:

1. Create a `Queue<DBRecord>`
2. Create one Thread(Task) to Enqueue items to this queue
3. Create 10-20 Threads(Tasks) to Dequeue the items and start calling this WebAPI through HttpClient
4. The 10-20 threads are storing the results into another results array or so.
5. Once the results array is large enough do the needful and store it to DB or what ever you want to do with it.

Hints:

- Queue and Results should be thread-safe or you can protect them with Mutex or Semaphore.
- You can not start a lot of threads(tasks) on the computer as each thread needs memory to keep track of its stack. So you will end out of memory.